# How to get an image with a NodeJS server and Angular Front?

Tags: html, node.js, angularjs, angular, multer

I have a problem... When I try to get an image that is saved on the server to view on the frontend, routes fail.

When I register one user, I save the user image in the server by `Multer` and I save the server image path in the user information of the database.

From the frontend, when I get one database user, I try to show their profile photo, but I get that the folder doesn't exist.

The hierarchy is as follows:

- Project

  - backend (NojdeJS)

    - imgs

      - image.jpg
  - frontend (Angular)

    - *Angular project*

From the frontend I want to access to the backend folder, but I get the following error:

```
GET http://localhost:4200/backend/users_imgs/image.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

At the moment, I call the image this way:

```
<img src="../../../../../../backend/users_imgs/image.jpg" alt="">
```

### EDIT

Following the @Ashish Yogi recomendations, I made this:

I have this in my back:

[image]

### app.js

[image]

And I have this on my front:

[image]
*Even though the path is that here, the real route is with users_imgs*

And as you can see in the next image, my server port is "4000":
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your image exists in the server folder, and you are trying to get it from angular URL. That's why it is not accessible.

You need to allow access to your images from Node Server.

First, move your imges folder to the public folder.

Your Node structure will look like this:

```
BackEnd (Node)
public
imges
image.jpg
```

You can allow the use of the public folder by below code:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
//serve public files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

now you can access the image with `http://localhost:SERVER_PORT/imges/image.jpg`

Comment: It desn't work for me. I edit my question so you can see it.

Comment: your public folder name is users_imgs, so your image path can be: http://localhost:4000/users_imgs/prueba.jpg

Comment: Nope, I have this: ```<img src="http://localhost:4000/users_imgs/prueba.jpg">``` and I get as if that path doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

The error was in using the following line:

[image]

I want to acces to public folder, but that path was *src/public/users_imgs*, when I have my public folder in *public/users_imgs*. Si I have used this:

`app.use(express.static('public'))`

I have tried this too, but it doesn't work and don't know why:

`app.use('/users_imgs', express.static('public'))`

And this, setting the public folder inside *src*:

`app.use('/users_imgs', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));
```

Note that: **../public** instead of **public**